# Need help understanding templated constructors in templated classes

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, c++14

I'm a template newb. This code (you can run it on [here on cpp.sh](https://cpp.sh/?source=%2F%2F+Example+program%0D%0A%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0D%0A%23include+%3Cvector%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T%3E%0D%0Aclass+ref_vector%0D%0A%7B%0D%0Apublic%3A%0D%0A%0D%0A++++%2F*!%0D%0A+++++*+Create+a+reference+vector+from+a+pointer.%0D%0A+++++*+%5Cparam+ptr+a+pointer+to+a+chunk+of+memory%0D%0A+++++*%2F%0D%0A++++template+%3Ctypename+Ptr%3E%0D%0A++++ref_vector(Ptr*+ptr)+%3A+_ptr(T(ptr))%0D%0A++++%7B%0D%0A++++++++%2F*+NOP+*%2F%0D%0A++++%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aprivate%3A%0D%0A++++const+T+_ptr%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Avoid+aargh(const+ref_vector%3Cvoid*%3E%26+ptr%2C+const+char+*s)+%7B%0D%0A++++std%3A%3Acout+%3C%3C+%22aargh+%22+%3C%3C+s+%3C%3C+std%3A%3Aendl%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aint+main()%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A++++std%3A%3Avector%3Cshort%3E+bozo(20)%3B%0D%0A++++std%3A%3Avector%3Cdouble%3E+clown(20)%3B%0D%0A++++aargh(%26bozo.front()%2C+%22is+short%22)%3B%0D%0A++++aargh(%26clown.front()%2C+%22is+double%22)%3B%0D%0A%7D)) has a template constructor in a template class. I pulled it from code that wants a pointer to the memory array of a vector to send/receive data in a radio, and the vector can be instantiated with different data types (short, long, double). The main code successfully passes references to two different types (short and double) to the function aargh's ptr argument.

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
class ref_vector
{
public:

    /*!
     * Create a reference vector from a pointer.
     * \param ptr a pointer to a chunk of memory
     */
    template <typename Ptr>
    ref_vector(Ptr* ptr) : _ptr(T(ptr))
    {
        /* NOP */
    }

private:
    const T _ptr;
};


void aargh(const ref_vector<void*>& ptr, const char *s) {
    std::cout << "aargh " << s << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<short> bozo(20);
    std::vector<double> clown(20);
    aargh(&bozo.front(), "is short");
    aargh(&clown.front(), "is double");
}
```

The program compiles and runs with C++14 without explicitly specifying a type for the ref_vector constructor. I don't understand what the template declaration of the constructor is doing, and how the compiler is inferring the type of Ptr in ref_vector. I don't know the terminology to describe what is going on here so I can search for an explanation.

Comment: Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: @NathanOliver - if you can recommend a particular book and a particular section within that book that addresses this issue, that would be really helpful.

Comment: The template section of any of the beginners books in the previous link will go into great detail on how templates work and how the compiler deduces the types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't understand what the template declaration of the constructor is doing, and how the compiler is inferring the type of Ptr in ref_vector.

```cpp
aargh(&bozo.front(), "is short");
aargh(&clown.front(), "is double");
```

You pass a `short*` and `double*` to a `ref_vector<void*>` constructors.

The constructors takes any pointer since they will be instantiated from a function template crafted to do so ...

```cpp
template <typename Ptr>
ref_vector(Ptr* ptr) : _ptr(T(ptr)) {}
//         ^^^^ any pointer will do
```

... which results in these two constructors being instantiated:

```cpp
ref_vector(short* ptr) : _ptr((void*) ptr) {}
ref_vector(double* ptr) : _ptr((void*) ptr) {}
```

It thereby converts whatever pointer it gets into a `void*` via the function style cast `T(ptr)` (since `T` is `void*`).

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize the compiler would implicitly determine the type of the function template from the call.